# iconv behaves differently on local machine

Tags: php

Have been trying to figure this out for 2 days, but with no success:

I have a very simple script that convert the french characters to non-french equivalents:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'fr_CA');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

$string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT',"montréal");
echo utf8_decode($string);
```

Remote server outputs

> montreal

Same script on local machine (MAMP on mac running PHP 5.4.4) outputs:

> montr'eal

What I have tried:

1) Made sure iconv is installed on the computer and tried reinstalling it using: $ brew install homebrew/dupes/libiconv (It says it's already there and I shouldn't touch it)

2) Compared phpinfo(); results and php.ini files on remote and local machines and there's no mention of iconv in either one. But I did notice that intl extension is not there on local machine, so not sure if it's related.

3) Tried "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/pecl install iconv"
It says: No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/iconv"

There's more information about indicating directives while compiling PHP, but this is way over my head. From what I understand it's a standard extension that enabled by default, so is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Thank you

Comment: What about the locales of both machine?

Comment: @ChinLeung hello fellow qc resident. I set them to setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'fr_CA'); on both. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @ChinLeung or did you mean "intl.default_locale", because i have in on the remote server but not on local